# Laptop Ram upgrade with ASUS GL752vl boot issue

Tags: windows-10, laptop, memory

I've recently bought this ram upgrade for my laptop unit (Kingston HyperX impact DDR4 2400mhz 16Gb x 2) which totals to 32GB worth of DDR4 ram. I understand based on the advertised specs of GL752vl on the asus page  its supposed to handle memory upgrade up to 32gb of ram. But in my case it doesn't work.
Upon installation of the 2 purchased RAMs, the laptop unit does not boot at all (Screen just goes black, and I can't access BIOS to see whats wrong. No beeping sound or any other indication something is going wrong). I am pretty sure however that both purchased ram are working perfectly as I've tried pairing each one of them with the stock rams (4GB that were already installed on my unit upon purchase) and the laptop boots completely without any problem. This however, can only provide me with 20GB worth of ram.

In Conclusion, the problem only occurs when I try to attach both 16 gb rams.

I did try those solutions from the net where you should try to swap the ram positions, remove and re-install the ram (to ensure that the ram is positioned correctly) etc. Is there something I'm missing here.

Comment: The specifications page says `DDR4 2133 MHz up to 32 GB`. My guess for the reason it's not working is because you got `2400 MHz` instead of `2133 MHz`.

Comment: @DrZoo I don't suppose the ram speed is the matter. I've just tried it with one 16gb (the newly purchased 2400mhz) ram attached to the laptop unit, and its working fine. Any other guesses?

Comment: And you used just one stick? Not one old one, and one new one?

Comment: Yes only one slot has been occupied by the 16gb stick, the other slot's free.

Comment: Maybe try reseating the second stick? It may have not been seated in all the way. You can also use both sticks of RAM in the single stick configuration, to ensure they are both working properly on their own.

Comment: Just tried it, both 16 gb ram work separately on their own, They still don't work no matter how many times i swap their places.

Comment: What version of Windows 10 are you running?

Comment: windows 10 64 bit Home

Comment: Sadly, I can't find much about this online. Do they both work individually in each slot?

Comment: They do worl actually, thanks for the help anyways. For now I'll just stick with my 1 old and 1 new configuration, Till I find something

Answer (score 0):

I would expect the ram not to work with the stock ram due to differences in speed of the ram as may happen on upgrading of ram for computers . Have you tried both separately without the stock ram to confirm they work alone.

Comment: Confirm this and we can trouble shoot it

Comment: Yup, just tested with 1 stick of the 16gb ram attached to the laptop unit and its working fine.

Comment: The best way out is to have ram sticks from the same manufacturer and same specifications .  It always works